# Calling another controller from service class in spring

Tags: spring

Is it a good practice to call a @controller class from @service class?

As currently i am directly calling controller from another controller(Spring Boot  Project),I am planning to introduce @service layer in between.

Please let me know

Comment: *Why* are you calling another controller? This usually just indicates a basic OO modeling problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not call a controller from a service layer directly. You might get circular dependencies.

I would use an [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) through dependency injection. When the controller implements an interface, you can autowire it into your service.

```
public interface Observer {

    void eventHappened();

}

@Controller
public class YourController implements Observer {

}

@Service
public class YourService {

    @Autowired
    private Observer o;

    // call o.eventHappened() somewhere in your code
}
```

If your controller also has a reference to your service, you might need to use [InitializingBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html) which you can use to register the observer.

Comment: Thanks for the replty but i missed to mention here I am talking about 2 different controllers.
Controller A calls Service class.Service class calls Controller B

Comment: You can apply the same pattern.

Comment: Thanks!! Will try to implement the same

Comment: What exactly will this accomplish? In his case, his controller C1 calls his other controller C2. Instead, code inside C1 should be moved to S1 and C2 to S2, then he should have a @Autowired lateinit service1: S1 inside S2 and S2 should call service1.functions()